# LinkedIn Javascript API not returning Position(end-date)

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, api, linkedin-api

For some reason the endDate of positions are hanging the whole script?

```
function importJobsEducation() {
  IN.API.Profile("me")
    .fields(["id","positions:(company,title,summary,start-date,end-date,is-current)", "educations","skills", "headline"])
    .result(function(result) {
      profile = result.values[0];

      $("#headline").val(profile.headline);
      $("#linkedInID").val(profile.id)

    positions = "";
for (var index=0; index < profile.positions.values.length; index++) {

    JobTitle = profile.positions.values[index].title
    jobSummary = profile.positions.values[index].summary
    isCurrent = profile.positions.values[index].isCurrent
    JstartMDate = profile.positions.values[index].startDate.month
    JstartYDate = profile.positions.values[index].startDate.year

    alert(profile.positions.values[index].endDate.month)

    if (isCurrent === false) {

        }

// Company Fields


OrgName  = profile.positions.values[index].company.name
companyType = profile.positions.values[index].company.companyType
size = profile.positions.values[index].company.size
industry = profile.positions.values[index].company.industry
ticker = profile.positions.values[index].company.ticker



}

    education = "";
for (var index=0; index < profile.educations.values.length; index++) {
    schoolName = profile.educations.values[index].schoolName    
    startDate = profile.educations.values[index].startDate.year
    EndDate = profile.educations.values[index].endDate.year

}

skills = "";    
for (var index=0; index < profile.skills.values.length; index++) {
skills += '<a href="" class="tag">'+ profile.skills.values[index].skill.name + '</a>&nbsp;';
}


    });
}
```

Comment: Where is the script hanging? Are there any errors generated?

Comment: The `alert(profile.positions.values[index].endDate.month)` part hangs the script no error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that current positions do not have an end date, and the way your code is written tries to fetch the endDate even for current positions.

Therefore, I suggest you have a conditional tag which check if this position is current, and if it isn't it fetches the end date. Example:

```
if (profile.positions.values[index].isCurrent === false) {
       endDate = profile.positions.values[index].endDate.month;
    }
```

I hope this helps.